# Why does my conditional formatting not working?

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The conditional formatting is

[image]

and the worksheet looks like this

[image]

Formula for the AL / MC:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F7),F8,IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F8)),EXACT(F7,F8)),F7,CONCATENATE(F7,CHAR(10),F8)))
```

For the above image, I have done the conditional formatting on the worksheet so that different category is highlighted but for the one with AL/MC together is not following the conditional formatting, any idea why is it so?

I tried to redo the conditional formatting and search for solutions online but just cannot get the AL/MC to change accordingly.

Comment: Please don't post formulas as image - instead as text within your question. It is then much easier to help you. Furthermore it would help to see your column headers in the screenshot of your sheet.